# EXCEL VBA overlap error

Tags: excel, vba

```
    Range("A1:C7").Select
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.EntireRow.Delete 
End Sub
```

This is part of a recorded VBA macro for deleting blank rows but it's showing an error `Run time error "1004" - "cannot use that command on overlapping selection"` in the line `Selection.EntireRow.Delete`.

What seems to be the problem?

Comment: The code won't work if you have blank cells in more than one column on the same row. You'll have to loop through the columns.

Comment: yes I have more than one blank cell in row .can you please provide any example considering three column "A","B","C" with loop code.

Answer (score 1):

A simple loop example:

```
Dim rgCol                 As Range
On Error Resume Next
For Each rgCol In Range("A1:C7").Columns
    rgCol.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
Next rgCol
```