# VBA code in two sheets fails in the second sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to run this VBA code in two sheets it works fine in first sheet but fails in the second sheet - any idea why?

The error is: **Run-time error '1004': Cannot use that command on overlapping selections.**

- The purpose of the VBA-code is to delete all blank rowns in the table.
- The range is separately named.
- I want to run the code just on the ActiveSheet when the button is hit.
- The button is only on a sheet.

---

```
Private Sub DeleteBlankRowsHoursTable_Click()
    Dim Rng As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    Set Rng = ActiveSheet.Range("DataHoursTable").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
        Rng.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Is hard-coding the range name a good idea?

Comment: For better answers, you need to provide more information. Is this CommandButton2 a button on a vba Userform or just on a sheet? Do both of the sheets in question have a separately scoped named range called DataHoursTable and you want this to run on just the sheet visible when the button is hit or on both in sequence? There are multiple ways to interpret your question which is why you're getting completely different solutions presented.

Comment: Thank you for advice. I have updated the question :)

Comment: I also forgot to mention : Define what you mean by 'Fails'. Is it erroring and breaking execution or erroring and not deleting rows you're expecting it to?

Comment: This seems to work for me and nothing looks suspect.  What sort of "fail" are you experiencing? Please provide more detail about the failure.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25600377/excel-vba-overlap-error) could help.

Comment: @Ioannis thanks it worls fine now - but it is very slow.
I'm just wondering how come  that the code works fine in the first sheet but not in the second sheet?

Comment: It is hard to say without looking at the data: it may be that in the first sheet all blanks were gathered in one column.. Yes, looping over columns is indeed slow. If this is a problem, there are way to deal with, but I think it merits to open a new question, as it is not the same as the current one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that range is available on both sheets? Try specifying the sheet.
If you change:

```
Set Rng = Range("DataHoursTable").Spec...
```

to

```
Set Rng = Activesheet.Range("DataHoursTable").Spec...
```

it will `Set` the Range to the named range on the currently active sheet.

Comment: I have changed the `Range`  to `ActiveSheet.Range` it still fails

Answer (score 0):

Edit (after reading updated question):
Your issue is that you have 2 sheets on which you want the same functionality. However, named ranges need to be unique, as well as the button names.

Thus:
On sheet 1, let's say the button is called "DeleteBlankRowsHoursTable1" and the named range / table you wish to run against is called "DataHoursTable1".
On sheet 2 the button will be called "DeleteBlankRowsHoursTable2" and the named range "DataHoursTable2".
Then, in the VBA editor, place the following code in Sheet 1:

```
Private Sub DeleteBlankRowsHoursTable1_Click()
    Dim Rng As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    Set Rng = Me.Range("DataHoursTable1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
        Rng.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    End If
End Sub
```

And in the second worksheet:

```
Private Sub DeleteBlankRowsHoursTable2_Click()
    Dim Rng As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    Set Rng = Me.Range("DataHoursTable2").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
        Rng.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    End If
End Sub
```

Note that you don't use "ActiveSheet", but rather "Me", since that references the sheet itself when coding inside the worksheet.

Comment: I have changed the button name and changed the `Range`  to `ActiveSheet.Range` it still fails